# Como fazer um ID auto incremento em relação a outro campo no PostgreSQL "PostgreSQL"?

Tags: banco-de-dados, postgresql, chave-primária, auto-incremento, chave-composta

Pessoal já faz um bom tempo em que eu procuro uma maneira de fazer isso, qual seria a maneira correta de fazer um auto incremento que depende de outro campo como no exemplo abaixo?

```
id_empresa | id_pedido
 1         | 1
 1         | 2
 1         | 3
 1         | 4
 2         | 1
 2         | 2
 3         | 1
```

Já cheguei a pensar em fazer somente uma trigger e procedure para todas as tabelas, só que não sei como fazer.

Um colega de trabalho me indicou fazer da seguinte forma:

1 Esse campo não faria parte da chave primária, então seria um id serial PK, id_empresa integer FK PK, num_ped integer.

2 Eu criar uma tabela sequencia_amigavel só para referenciar esses ids, por exemplo um registro nesta tabela seria, (pedido, 1) e suas colunas seriam (tabela, sequencia).

3 Toda vez que eu fizer um pedido eu faço um UPDATE com RETURNING na tabela sequencia_amigavel.

4 Recebendo esse valor eu dou um INSERT na tabela pedido

Comment: nesse caso não seria um `id`, mas um código que varia de acordo com outra coluna.. sendo assim, ele não pode ser auto incrementável e deve ser controlado manualmente (pelo menos até onde entendo de _postgresql_).

Comment: @rLinhares como que eu controlaria manualmente sem dar problema de concorrência? Eu preciso chegar nesse resultado, Será que funcionaria sem problemas se eu fizesse em um sql somente, um insert consultando o valor máximo +1? Sem precisar bloquear a tabela?

Comment: esses dois campos são da mesma tabela? se sim, não precisaria bloqueá-la, já que o _sgbd_ faz isso na hora do _insert_.

Comment: @rLinhares mas será que ele faz isso, bloquear a tabela, na hora do INSERT INTO pedido(id_empresa, id_pedido) VALUES (1,(SELECT max(id_pedido) + 1 FROM pedido))

Comment: sim, pode ir que é sucesso =p Rovann postou como [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/347501/64073) ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui pessoal

Com base neste [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9984196/postgresql-gapless-sequences) e com um pouco de melhoria, segue abaixo o resultado final

```
-- tabela onde ficará guardado as sequências de cada loja tabela e coluna
    CREATE TABLE public.sequencia_tabelas (
    id_empr integer NOT NULL,
    id_filial character(14) NOT NULL,
    tabela varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    coluna varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    proximo_indice integer NOT NULL
    );

ALTER TABLE public.sequencia_tabelas OWNER TO postgres;

ALTER TABLE ONLY public.sequencia_tabelas
    ADD CONSTRAINT sequencia_tabelas_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id_empr, id_filial, tabela, coluna);

COMMENT ON TABLE public.sequencia_tabelas
    IS 'Tabela de sequências amigáveis por empresa, filial, tabela e coluna';

-- Exemplo de inserção
-- INSERT INTO sequencia_tabelas(id_empr, id_filial, tabela, coluna, proximo_indice) 
-- VALUES ('1', '12345678910111', 'pedido', 'numero_pedido', '0');



-- function proximo id
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION proximo_id(id_empr text, id_filial text, tabela text, coluna text) RETURNS integer AS $$
DECLARE
    proximo_valor integer;
BEGIN
    EXECUTE format('UPDATE sequencia_tabelas SET proximo_indice = proximo_indice + 1 WHERE id_empr = %L AND id_filial = %L AND tabela = %L AND coluna = %L RETURNING proximo_indice', id_empr, id_filial, tabela, coluna) INTO proximo_valor;
    RETURN proximo_valor;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

COMMENT ON FUNCTION proximo_id(text, text, text, text) IS 'Incrementa e retorna o valor da coluna inteira $2 na tabela $1';

-- Exemplo de inserção
-- INSERT INTO pedido(id_empr, id_filial, numero_pedido, emissao, observacoes) 
-- VALUES ('1', '12345678910111', proximo_id('1','12345678910111','pedido','numero_pedido'), LOCALTIMESTAMP, 'teste id');
```

Answer (score 1):

A princípio, como rLinhares falou, não é uma PK, logo você deve mandar isso ao banco.

uma simples sub-query resolve o problema:

```
insert into pedidos (id_pedido,id_empresa) values ((select coalesce(max(id_pedido),0) + 1 from pedidos where id_empresa = 1 ), 1) returning id_pedido;
```

O coalesce, serve para o primeiro pedido, que é quando não há nenhum, ele deve retornar 0.

Repare que o valor da id_empresa é utilizado duas vezes.

Fugindo um pouco a pergunta, e me adiantando, todo pedido deve ter itens, nesse caso utilizei o returning que será a FK na tabela dos itens (deve ser uma FK composta com empresa, pedido, item) e para manter a integridade, isso tudo deve estar dentro de uma transação.

Comment: o id_pedido e id_empresa são uma PK

Comment: Só que me disseram que. "Nesse caso não terá bloqueio nenhum. Terá uma leitura da tabela pedido para computar um valor e depois um insert. Sem transações, locks e isolamento, nada te garante que outra conexão simultânea irá computar o mesmo valor de id_pedido"

Comment: difícil, talvez improvável... e se acontecer, o próprio banco iria retornar uma exceção de duplicação de chave primária para uma das duas transações. Isso pode ser solucionado alterando nível de isolamento da transação para `serializable` mas fica mais lento e pode dar outros problemas se as transações forem muito longas. Mas no geral, da forma que está não dá problema. Sobre a PK, sim a PK é composta com pedido e empresa, então pedido é parte da PK e não a PK em si, por isso o banco não "toma conta" pra fazer esse auto-incremento

Comment: Um colega de trabalho me indicou fazer da seguinte forma,
1 Esse campo não faria parte da chave primária, então seria um id serial PK, id_empresa integer FK PK, num_ped integer.
2 Eu criar uma tabela sequencia_amigavel só para referenciar esses ids, por exemplo um registro nesta tabela seria, (pedido, 1) e suas colunas seriam (tabela, sequencia)
3 Toda vez que eu fizer um pedido eu faço um UPDATE com RETURNING na tabela sequencia_amigavel.
4 Recebendo esse valor eu dou um INSERT na tabela pedido

Comment: nem faria esse se fosse o caso... pouco importa ter o id 3, e o próximo ser o 7 para uma empresa, ainda mais SERIAL, que se uma transação falha o número é perdido... faria só a PK serial simples e uma FK da empresa e bola pra frente... no caso de notas fiscais (onde é necessário seguir a numeração) por exemplo, segue dessa forma e faz uma UK com (serie, modelo, numero, emitente)